# Does this ROM Chip Require a Level Shifter on the SPI lines?

Tags: spi

I have this ROM chip: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/adesto-technologies/AT25SL321-MBUE-T/6827495

I see it takes ~1.8V nominal input - do the 3.3V SPI lines need to be level-shifted down to 1.8V?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [data sheet](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/590/AT25SL321_112-1385816.pdf) is quite clear: -

[image]

So, if running at 1.8 volts, the maximum voltage from a 3.3 volt powered device should be a little below 2.2 volts. This may indeed require some form of level shifter and, you may need to use a level shifter on the output to the 3.3 volt devices to ensure a read operation is successful.

Comment: I was just looking at that.  You're right of course, but the absolute maximum for Vcc in that table is nonsense.  One might ask, "can you choose Vcc=3.3V"?  It looks from the rest of the datasheet that max Vcc is 2V, but that entry on that table is an error.  I can't find a better datasheet, despite trying.  Frankly, when I'm upset with a datasheet, I move on to the next chip.

Comment: @ScottSeidman total pants that line in the DS

Answer (score 3):

This is a 1.8 V flash chip (not a ROM), and the [datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/590/AT25SL321_112-1385816.pdf) states that VCC is to be between 1.7 and 2.0 V. The absolute maximum rating for data pin voltages is VCC + 0.4 V, so a level shifter is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the IO pins can't work with 3.3V.